# Adding numbers to variables within an if statement

Tags: python, list, variables, if-statement, tuples

I am working on a program that will choose a random winner depending on the number they are given. I have completed this program, however I am having trouble finding a solution to one particular thing.

Here is my code:

```
    player1Luck = 0
    player1Luck = player1Luck / 2
    player1Luck = player1Luck + 15
    if player1Luck > 50:
        player1Luck = player1Luck + 30
        probabilities.extend([player1] * int(player1Luck))
        print(player1Luck)
        print(player1 + " Your number is:", str(player1num) + "! You have a percentage to win of: ", str(player1Luck) + "%!")
    else:
        probabilities.extend([player1] * int(player1Luck))
        print(player1 + " Your number is:", str(player1num) + "! You have a percentage to win of: ", str(player1Luck) + "%!")
```

So, the first part (before the if statement) is completely fine, numbers are adding up etc perfectly. It's only when inside of the if statement that numbers are adding up wrongly. For example I said to add an extra 30 to the player1Luck variable if it is above 50, instead the number is drastically low to what it used to be before I decided to implement this feature. Here is what my code looked like before I changed the variable names and such to try and fix this problem.

```
newnum = player2num / 2
newnumadded = newnum + 10
if newnumadded > 50:
    bonusnum = newnumadded + 50
    print(player2 + " Your number is:", str(player2num) + "! You have a percentage to win of: ", str(bonusnum) + "%!")
    probabilities.extend([player2] * int(bonusnum))
else:
    print(player2 + " Your number is:", str(player2num) + "! You have a percentage to win of: ", str(newnumadded) + "%!")
    probabilities.extend([player2] * int(newnumadded))
```

I am aware the problem could lie in some mistyped code but I have looked through it thoroughly and am struggling quite badly, I am also quite new to Python so structuring code may be quite insufficient from myself.

Comment: I highly recommend getting to know [pdb](https://pymotw.com/2/pdb/) the Python debugger. It is invaluable in cases like this.

Comment: other than that, if you are using those first 3 lines exactly, then your `player1Luck` is always 15 right before checks. I don't see why are you assinging 0 to it or what were you expecting from those.

Comment: @Lafexlos print statement debugging is definitely useful, and is always my first avenue, but if I'm not sure what's *really* going on, I'll pick up pdb. Or pudb, nowadays.

Comment: Like I said I haven't been programming for a while, and I am just wondering what the issue is.. does anybody know?

Comment: @MattJones it looks like the issue is that you haven't provided quite enough code for us to be able to tell. I notice that you've got `player1num` instead of `player2num`. As Lafexlos mentioned, you're setting `player1Luck = 0` - it's never going to be anything besides zero. As an aside, sample input and expected output are always helpful.

Comment: @WayneWerner I can provide the full program as necessary, it would probably make a lot more sense. And I have given the     player1Luck a value of     0 so that when I use mathematical operators later on in the code I can change the number that it will be.